# minionpro: using the number 3 in italic causes an error

Tags: fonts, errors, minionpro

I'm experiecing a rather strange bug with the `minionpro` package. When using lining figures (package option `lf`), the number 3 in `\itshape` produces the following error:

```
!pdfTeX error: /usr/texbin/pdflatex (file /usr/local/texlive/2013/../texmf-
local/fonts/type1/adobe/MinionPro/MinionPro-It.pfb): 
CharString (/three.fitted): command not valid: 0
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

This happens only with the number `3`, only in `italic` and only when using the `lf` option (minionpro uses old style figures by default).
It's worth mentioning that I used [FontPro](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro) to install `minionpro`.

Here's an MWE that produces the error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lf]{MinionPro}
\begin{document}

\itshape Number 3

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm using MiKTeX 2.9 and have also used FontPro to install `minionpro`, but I can't seem to reproduce that error. Your MWE works fine for me.

Comment: If you don't mind checking, what version of the `Minion Pro` font did you use? I used 2.112 from the latest version of Adobe Reader for OS X.

Comment: My working version is `Version 2.030;PS 2.000;hotconv 1.0.51`. To notify a previous commenter, remember to mention his or her name using the `@` symbol, e.g. `@nnunes`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The bug in `cfftot1` has been fixed](https://github.com/kohler/lcdf-typetools/commit/a34cb53e864cfbdc6808761a1257cd5fb16eb25b) in lcdf-typetools version 2.99. Use this version with recent Minion Pro font versions.

Answer (score 3):

I got in contact with the author of `FontPro` and he was able to reproduce the issue. It turns out that the latest version of the `MinionPro` font (v2.112, supplied with Adobe Reader for Mac) was not playing nice with `FontPro` and the conversion proccess. Using the font supplied with Adobe Reader for Linux (v2.068) solved the problem.

Here you can see the `three.fitted` glyph that was causing the error:

[image: minionpro three.fitted glyph error]